# Como funciona o merge?

Tags: git, versionamento, merge

Eu criei outra *branch* como backup e dou `merge` nela, suponha que estou na *branch* `daniela3`:

```
git merge origin/develop
```

Só a minha *branch* `daniela3` vai ser afetada ou `origin/develop` também? Digo, vou estar juntando o que tem em `origin/develop` -> `daniela3` e `origin/develop` permanece sem minhas alterações OU as duas são atualizadas?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Só o repositório que você está no momento é atualizado (no caso deve ser o `daniela3` se entendi certo). Se você deseja que outro repositório seja atualizado (não que pareça ser o seu caso) você terá que fazer um `push` para ele.

Então o `merge` é local sempre. Quando você deseja atualizar outro repositório você traz seu conteúdo para o seu repositório local atual, faz o `merge` e manda de volta o conteúdo do seu repositório para o repositório original, possivelmente remoto.

O `merge` só age no repositório atual considerando as diferenças para o repositório específico que está conectado. Quaisquer outros *branches* não são considerados. Caso haja necessidade de considerar outros *branches*, estes devem ser mesclados antes no repositório devido.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quando dou "git pull" me trás a atualização (aquilo que foi enviado em "git push") de TODOS os branches remotos? Qual a diferença pull VS merge?

Comment: Bom, isto já é outra pergunta :) mas `git pull` traz apenas o que está no repositório onde você está se conectando. Se ele possui *branches* que não foram mesclados estes não são considerados.

Comment: Entendi, obrigada!

Answer (score 3):

Apenas a branch **em que você está** é afetada. No caso, apenas a branch `daniela3`.

Isto ocorre porque a branch `origin/develop` é a branch de origem. Se visualizar as branches do Git como grafos, fica fácil entender que a branch não é afetada. Isto pode ser mostrado visualmente, com a situação das branches **antes**:

```
                  .----C1<----C2        <- [daniela3]
                 /                    
M1<---M2<---M3<-´---M4<---M5<---M6      <- [origin/develop]
```

E **depois** do merge, gerando o commit de merge `C3m`:

```
                  .----C1<----C2<-----C3m        <- [daniela3]
                 /                    /
M1<---M2<---M3<-´---M4<---M5<---M6<--´           <- [origin/develop]
```

Veja que a branch `origin/develop` permanece intacta